# How and where to mention our existing web url in Tauri application?

Tags: tauri

[dev path mentioned file(tauri.config.json)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAa1H.png)[default server mentioned file(vite.config.js)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq8Fh.png)
I'm facing difficulty to run my website through Tauri application

I have created Tauri application using **vite** framework and when I am trying to run the application it takes default port number which is mentioned in **vite.config.js**.And I have mentioned my url in "devpath" under build in **tauri.config.json**
I expected that when I run the server, I would need to host my website on the server.